# How to base64 encode an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova, base64

I am developing a phonegap application and using the `navigator.getPicture` method to get the images.

The way I am getting the picture is:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}
```

Just like the example in phonegap doc's.

I want to be able to use the imageURI and then convert it to image data in order to upload it later. (I don't want to use phonegap's FileTransfer)

So far I have tried both [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) and [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript)

When I try the following,

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    getBase64Image(imageURI);
}

function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

   // Get the data-URL formatted image
   // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
   // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
   // will re-encode the image.
   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

   console.log(dataURL); //here is where I get 'data:,'       

   return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

And print `dataURL` before returning. I just get `data:,` as the content.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SQ. Very good first question! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try getting it as a DATA_URL. Your mileage may vary as you could run into an out of memory error when the image is converted to a Base64 string.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader_read_as_data_url).

The canvas.toDataURL method is not implemented on earlier versions of Android.

Comment: Hi Simon, I tried doing the readAsDataURL but had no luck with it. I didn't want to use DATA_URL but I think it might be the only option. Thanks.